# ubuntu has stopped connecting to wifi router

Tags: networking, wireless

I've been using Ubuntu 16.04 for almost a year now, and for some reason yesterday and today I haven't been able to connect to the wifi router. I've had many problems in the past, but it has been stable for months - and yesterday it just stopped connecting. It still sees all the networks, and tries to connect to my network but just keeps showing the "connecting" animation where the wifi pulses up.

There's nothing wrong with the router or wifi receiver - I can connect fine on my macbook, phones, and my desktop is dual boot with windows/ubuntu with the windows partition connecting fine with the same wifi dongle.

I'm really just not sure how to debug this, and with all the wifi connectivity problems of 16.04, I haven't found much on my specific problem. I've tried reconnecting and restarting the computer, router, wifi dongle. I have a command I sometimes use `sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service`, but it doesn't have any effect in this instance. I tried manually setting the time to be correct, with no difference.

Looking for any ideas of what the problem may be, or any advice on what I can do to help debug this issue.

Comment: Have you tried connecting via ethernet?

Comment: nope, ethernet isn't an option at the moment.

Comment: @NerdOfCode ok i made it possible today (to help debug, update drivers, update ubuntu, etc), and yes it works fine using ethernet.